# Scout SDK: SKReverseGeocoderManager.getInstance().reverseGeocodePosition(position) return offlinePackageCode=null

Tags: android, skmaps

Using ScoutSDK I am Reverse Geocode some coordinates. Returned results are all fine except offlinePackageCode, which value is always null.

Is it kind of bug, or? I am using sample from here http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec021

Comment: If you don't have an offline package already downloaded, and you do the reverse geocaching on the cached data then it's normal that the offlinePackageCode is null (as no offline package was used for this operation).

Comment: @Ando I have 2 pre-packaged map files on my device.

Comment: @Ando, would you please verify this?